# Unable to find file under resources folder

Tags: scala

When I run my app in sbt console `my-app/run` (my-app is a module), I get this error

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:.../target/bg-jobs/sbt_eea980c4/job-3/target/aaa32a5e/b2227e4f/my-app_2.13-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/my_file.csv`

My directory structure is `my-app->src->main->resources->my_file.csv`. The way I am accessing the file in my code is:

```
val file = new File(getClass.getResource("/my_file.csv").getPath)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sbt stuck your resources in a jar, so you can't access them as a file. You can use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my_file.csv")` instead.